# Display selected columns based on field condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I can get a sorted output of selected columns in Pandas like this:

```
df[['column A', 'column B', 'column E']].sort_values('column B')
```

I can get an output containing all columns based on a certain field condition like this:

```
df[df['File Type'] == 'mp4'].sort_values('column B'))
```

I can't find the correct syntax for combining both, i.e. getting only the 3 columns in the first statement based on the condition in the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filtering and select specific columns using a list:

```
df.loc[df['File Type'] == 'mp4', ['column A', 'column B', 'column E']].sort_values('column B')
```